# angular directive - transclude with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, directive

can transclude and templateUrl work together in a directive?

I'm trying to make a dynamic modal directive that supports html.

modal.js

```
'use strict';

myApp.directive('siteModal', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "./components/modal/modal.html",
    };
});
```

modal.html

```
<div class="site-modal">

    <div class="site-modal-content">

        <div class="site-modal-body">
            {{modalContent}}
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="site-modal-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<div site-modal ng-transclude>
    Hello World <strong>and maybe some HTML too!</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: you have `ng-transclude` in the wrong place.  `ng-transclude` goes *inside the template*, as the marker for where the transcluded content should be inserted into the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to work together. You have just misplaced ng-transclude attribute.

```
<div class="site-modal">

    <div class="site-modal-content">

        <div class="site-modal-body">
            <p ng-transclude> </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="site-modal-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that's awkward. Thank you for noticing.